# How can I effectively "support bait"?

Tags: league-of-legends

I got a taste of this playing as Sona. I was warding the map with my team waiting unseen in a nearby bush. Since it appeared that I was alone, the enemy team jumped me. I died, but my team managed to dispatch the enemies.

What are the specific conditions needed for a successful support bait, and when should I try to pull it off? Specific gameplay examples would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you already figured it out and just wanted to share your story with us. Please clarify your question so we can understand exactly what you want us to answer.

Comment: While I find it a good story I must agree with @StrixVaria

Comment: does this help?

Comment: I've voted to re-opened your question since it's now clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make sure your teammates know what you are planning and are also in a good position to follow up when you get initiated.

I think baiting your opponents with Sona is very risky as her ultimate and abilities are very helpful to the team and she is incredibly squishy so she could be killed before your team could engage and punish the enemy team. I think it would instead be better to use a more tanky champion that can also hold them in-place or stun them (Rammus and Jarvan), or a champion that has escapes/can disengage (Akali and Kassadin).

As to how to bait the enemy team into falling for the trap, that is very tricky. You need to make the other team think that you are alone. One way of doing this would be for the bait to stand in an enemy team's ward while their allies don't stand in visibility of the ward.

If for whatever reason the enemy team looks too strong or you don't think you can take them in the fight let the person being the bait die and disengage. It is much better to only have 1 person die than the entire team.

There are also some Champions that have abilities relating to death that can enhance your plays, here are some examples:

**Karthus**: He can cast spells for 7 seconds after being killed thanks to his Death Defied passive.
**Kayle**: Her ultimate makes a champion immune to damage (2/2.5/3 seconds)
**Kog'Maw**: Moves faster and blows up after 4 seconds dealing 100 + (24 x lvl) true damage. During the early mor middle game where Kog'Maw isn't fed, it might not be a bad idea to bait with him, but once he starts getting to late game I don't think it would be a good idea to bait him.

Comment: Other strong support-bait champions include Leona and Zyra, since even if they die, they've made up their usefulness anyway: Leona can blow off her ult and Q, as well as putting her passive on everyone with W. Zyra can root the entire team, throw down her ult, and then, after death, deal true damage.

Comment: @Schism Those are all excellent suggestions. I think I missed out on a few points of champions that have skills relating to taking damage and death (Kayle, Karthus, Trynd, Zilean and Yorick to name a few) I didn't initially want to include an exhaustive list as well there are a lot of champs but it might be good to include a few more examples.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite time to support bait is in lane when my jungler is approaching for a gank. I typically play Morgana support, which I consider a safe but effective champion for this scenario. As the jungler approaches (either via river or lane bush), I try to bait the enemy into thinking that they are able to get an easy kill on me. Perhaps I will intentionally be Thresh-hooked, walk close to the ADC and trade autos, or stand in a known-warded bush. The enemies are often so concerned that even if my jungler is visible in their wards, they will be so distracted by me that they don't notice him. This can allow me to lure the enemies into a good position for the jungler to reach them and my ADC to finish them off.

I do want to note that I typically won't make this play if I don't have flash available. I don't often consider my death in this situation to be "worth".